# Sql query to pull records comparing 2 different rows if certain columns match

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to figure out this sql query and I am stuck.

I have this table:

| Identifier | entity_name | date_1 | date_2 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | A | 6-Dec-23 | 7-Dec-23 | 15 |
| abc | B | 6-Dec-23 | 7-Dec-23 | 16 |
| xyz | A | 12-Dec-23 | 14-Dec-23 | 18 |
| xyz | B | 15-Dec-23 | 61-Dec-23 | 18 |
| cde | A | 12-Dec-23 | 14-Dec-23 | 19 |
| cde | B | 12-Dec-23 | 14-Dec-23 | 19 |
| abc | A | 6-Nov-23 | 7-Nov-23 | 15 |
| abc | B | 6-Nov-23 | 7-Nov-23 | 16 |

I only want to query to compare rows and get the rows where following conditions are fulfilled:

- entity_name A row is compared to entity_name B row. Rows where entity_name is same are not compared against eack other
- entity_name column might have more values than A and B as mentioned in the table. But i am only trying to compare for entity_value A against B.
- value in identifier column is same
- date_1 and date_2 are same
- date_1 is greater than current date
- if quantity value for entity_name=A is less than entity_name=B

> ***So based on these conditions from the table mentioned above only first 2 rows will be pulled.***

I am not sure how to compare rows against each other where certain column values are same and some of them are not in SQL.
Is it best to do this in SQL or should I try this in python (pandas)?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. You can put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. I.e. provide a a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
with temp as (
  select *
  from your_table
  where entity_name in ('A', 'B')
  and parse_date('%d-%B-%y', date_1) > current_date()
)
select t.* from (
  select [t1, t2] arr
  from temp t1
  join temp t2
  on t1.Identifier = t2.Identifier
  and t1.date_1 = t2.date_1
  and t1.date_2 = t2.date_2
  and t1.entity_name ='A'
  and t2.entity_name ='B'
  and t1.quantity < t2.quantity
), unnest(arr) t
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `count()` to find identifiers that have both **entity_name**s. and `min()/max()` combined with `case` clause to retrieve quantity of both entities :

```
with cte as (
  select *, count(*) over (Identifier_window) as cnt,
            min(case when entity_name = 'A' then quantity end) over (Identifier_window) as quantity_A,
            min(case when entity_name = 'B' then quantity end) over (Identifier_window) as quantity_B
  from tmp
  where entity_name in ('A', 'B') and parse_date('%d-%B-%y', date_1) > current_date()
  window Identifier_window AS (partition by Identifier, date_1, date_2)
)
select Identifier, entity_name, date_1, date_2, quantity
from cte
where cnt = 2 and quantity_A < quantity_B
```

Result :

| Identifier | entity_name | date_1 | date_2 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | A | 6-Dec-23 | 7-Dec-23 | 15 |
| abc | B | 6-Dec-23 | 7-Dec-23 | 16 |

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY identifier, date_1, date_2
  ORDER BY entity_name
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (a b)
  DEFINE
    a AS  entity_name = 'A'
      AND date_1 > SYSDATE,
    b AS  entity_name = 'B'
      AND quantity > a.quantity
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Identifier, entity_name, date_1, date_2, quantity) AS
SELECT 'abc', 'A', DATE '2023-12-06', DATE '2023-12-07', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'B', DATE '2023-12-06', DATE '2023-12-07', 16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 'A', DATE '2023-12-12', DATE '2023-12-14', 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz', 'B', DATE '2023-12-15', DATE '2023-12-16', 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cde', 'A', DATE '2023-12-12', DATE '2023-12-14', 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cde', 'B', DATE '2023-12-12', DATE '2023-12-14', 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'A', DATE '2023-11-06', DATE '2023-11-07', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'B', DATE '2023-11-06', DATE '2023-11-07', 16 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| IDENTIFIER | DATE_1 | DATE_2 | ENTITY_NAME | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2023-12-06 00:00:00 | 2023-12-07 00:00:00 | A | 15 |
| abc | 2023-12-06 00:00:00 | 2023-12-07 00:00:00 | B | 16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WuQ8tb6L)